# tense with preposition

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, tense

> 1a.  This football team won the league championship 3 times **over** the last 5 years.
>   1b.  This football team won the league championship 3 times **during** the last 5 years.
>   1c.  This football team won the league championship 3 times **in** the last 5 years.
>
> 2a.  This football team **has** won the league championship 3 times **over** the last 5 years.
>   2b.  This football team **has** won the league championship 3 times **during** the last 5 years.
>   2c.  This football team **has** won the league championship 3 times **in** the last 5 years.
>
> 3a. He achieved great success **over** the last 5 years.
>   3b. He achieved great success **during** the last 5 years.
>   3c. He achieved great success **in** the last 5 years.
>
> 4a. He **has** achieved great success **over** the last 5 years.
>   4b. He **has** achieved great success **during** the last 5 years.
>   4c. He **has** achieved great success **in** the last 5 years.

For these sentences, we have three choices for the preposition.  How do we choose?  Does the tense of the sentences (past *vs.* present perfect) influence the choice?

Comment: This question is different from the "possible duplicate".  All of the examples in the "possible duplicate" are in the present perfect tense.  Whereas this question specifically asks how changing from past tense to present perfect tense influences the choice of preposition.

Comment: The tenses (simple past/past perfect) have no bearing on the preposition.

Answer (score 1):

Any of these sentences could be used without objection. Choosing between them is difficult in the absence of additional contextual data with which to inform that choice.

'The last five years'is a period of time stretching from five years ago to the present time. As this period includes the present, I would be more comfortable using the present perfect tense than the past tense. As a consequence I would prefer the answers in sections 2 and 4 over those in sections 1 and 3.

Within section 2, I think 2c is the best option. Although you have to win many games to eventually win the league championship, there is actually only one day in each year where a team can say, 'We have won the league championship.' This means that during a five year period this team could only say that on three occasions. It seems to me that three days within a five year period is better described by using **in** than **during** or **over**.  So, I would prefer to say:

> They won many games **during/over** the last five years.

however

> They won the league championship three times **in** the last five years.

Using similar reasoning, I would not use **in** in section 4, unless the writer wants to imply that someone achieved  great success once during a five year period. Instead, I think that the writer means that someone has worked hard for five years culminating in the achievement of great success.

This leaves a choice between 4b or 4c. Given a choice between **over** or **during**, I personally prefer to use **over** when talking about regular or continuous activity throughout a period of time. **During** can be used for the same purpose, but I tend to use **during** for activities that occurred off and on over a period of time, or for an activity that occurred for a shorter period of time during a longer period of time. So my choice would be 4c.

Answer (score 0):

**It is not the tense that calls for a preposition.** It is the **verb**.

over the last few years, in the last few years, during the last five years
have to do with the verbs achieve and win, not their tenses.

I will pass on reposting all the examples from the question.

You can **achieve or win** something in some period of time, over a period of time or during a period of time.